# i18next load the translation file only once from remote

Tags: next.js, localization, internationalization, i18next

I have a NextJS application that uses 18next for localisation and it loads the translation files from another server.
The translation files are different for each language, but they contain all the namespaces in one place, so i18next is trying to load the same file over and over (for each namespace there is).

I looked over what configs i can change and i managed to reduce the number of requests from the count of namespaces to the count of the namespaces in the current page, but still i would like just to have one request.

Is there any config i can update so i18next will not care about the namespaces when it makes the request?

Comment: Please share what configs you have applied so far.

Answer (score 1):

[i18next](https://www.i18next.com/) has an `ns` configuration setting where you specify the [namespaces](https://www.i18next.com/principles/namespaces) you want to use.
By default, i18next will try to load each namespace separately.

Bit: if you have *one* file that contains *multiple namespaces* and want to avoid reloading the file for each namespace, you can take advantage of the custom [`loadPath` function in the `i18next-http-backend`](https://github.com/i18next/i18next-http-backend#backend-options).
That would allow you to load the file only once regardless of how many namespaces are requested.

A possible setup would be:

```js
i18n
  .use(Backend) 
  .init({
    lng: 'en',
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    preload: ['en'], 
    ns: ['namespace1', 'namespace2', 'namespace3'], // All your namespaces
    defaultNS: 'namespace1',
    backend: {
      loadPath: function (langs, namespaces) {
        // Load a single file per language
        return `https://my-remote-server.com/locales/${langs[0]}.json`;
      },
    },
  });
```

In that configuration, regardless of which namespace is requested, the same translation file for the current language is loaded.

Note: Ensure that you are using i18next version >= 19.0.1, as older versions have a bug where the `ns` option is not correctly respected in some cases.
And use namespaces without space in their name ([issue 1970](https://github.com/i18next/i18next/issues/1970))

You should have your translations in your JSON file structured with namespaces:

```json
{
  "namespace1": {
    "key1": "translation1",
    "key2": "translation2"
  },
  "namespace2": {
    "key1": "translation1",
    "key2": "translation2"
  },
  "namespace3": {
    "key1": "translation1",
    "key2": "translation2"
  }
}
```

That way, you load all namespaces at once in one file per language and avoid multiple requests.

Check out also the recent (June 2023) [`i18next/i18next` issue 1966](https://github.com/i18next/i18next/issues/1966), which refers to using [`withTranslation` (HOC)](https://react.i18next.com/latest/withtranslation-hoc): a classic HOC (higher order component) and gets the `t` function and i18n instance inside your component via props.